# High pressure cooker classic vs electric multipurpose

Tags: equipment, pressure-cooker, kitchen-safety, safety, efficiency

I was looking to buy a pressure cooker and I see that besides the classic ones with the valve that you put on the kitchen stove there are some that are electric and also multifunctional i.e. pressure cooker, slow cooker etc.
My question is in terms of safety is there any difference between the classic and the electric multicooker with setting for high pressure cooking?

**Update**
Just for context in case it matters my main interest is legumi.

Comment: The electric cooker has a timer and automatically regulates the power. Nothing will burn.

Comment: @LookAlterno: So the pros are it is easier to use and safer? Is the con the more cooking time?

Comment: I don't don't know if it's slower, but it required no time/attention from me.

Answer (score 3):

There should not be safety concerns when properly using any modern pressure cookers.  They all have multiple safety triggers.  You may want to compare venting vs. non-venting (some believe non-venting preserves aromatics better).  Also some electric models max out at a lower pressure then stove top, spring valve models.

Comment: `Also some electric max out at a lower pressure then stove top models` does that mean it takes more time to cook? Also what should I check to verify that?

Comment: @Jim it depends, but in general higher pressure = faster.  Just check max psi of the models you are comparing. Upper end on a stove top model is usually listed at 15psi.

Comment: I don't see psi mentioned though e.g. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Tefal-CY505E40-Electric-Pressure-Stainless/dp/B07C1MPN1S/ref=sr_1_3?crid=3I45B48YGLEWH&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.ope7l9nNfY-_8-_cLQV8WQ.EoJW55jMrxmXI0Yt-MwuKDmozDsTBt1ESU8QenMMmYU&dib_tag=se&keywords=B07C1MPN1S&qid=1708978504&sprefix=b07c1mpn1s%2Caps%2C58&sr=8-3

Comment: @Jim go directly to Tefal website. It maxes out at slightly over 10psi.

Comment: Re. the pressure level: it is a small difference in cooking time (but you will soon learn what your preferred timings are, even recipes can have a certain range depending on ingredient selection and cut size), but relevant if you want to do pressure canning. Then authorities demand a certain pressure level for a safe product.

Comment: That said, I know and have used both and would always and without hesitation pick the electric one. Personal preference, of course.

Comment: @Stephie: What is "pressure canning"? Also why would you always pick the electric one?

Comment: @Jim pressure cookers, electric or stove top, are not recommended for pressure canning.  One would need a dedicated pressure canner, made specifically for canning. This has more to do with size and heating and cooling rates.

Comment: @Jim happy to explain my reasoning in [chat].

Comment: @Stephie: I didn't see that chat and I don't see an option to reply there. So basically convenience but what is the difference in cooking time. For context my main interest is legumes.

Comment: @moscafj: I see here https://www.tefal.co.uk/Cooking-appliances/Pressure-Cookers/Pressure-Cookers/Tefal-All-in-One-CY505-Pressure-Cooker-%E2%80%93-6L-Black-%26-Stainless-Steel-/p/7211003272 that it mentions `70kPa (Up to 5x faster than pot cooking*)` What does that mean? Where does it say slightly over 10psi?

Comment: @Jim 70kPa = 10.1526 psi